"Reiß ab, wo Schloss und Riegel für." - For what?
In the Christmas song 'O Heiland, reiß die Himmel auf' (text 1622) the first verse is as below.
What is the most literal translation of the last line, and does it sound strange/archaic/poetic to modern ears?
'Tear off, where lock and bar [are] for [i.e. used, on the gate & door]' ?
O Heiland, reiß die Himmel auf,
herab, herab vom Himmel lauf,
reiß ab vom Himmel Tor und Tür,
reiß ab, wo Schloss und Riegel für.

You may want to take into account that we're talking about a song text from almost exactly four centuries ago. In poems, song lyrics and the like there's a larger degree of leeway for "mangling" the language, in order to fit the rhyme scheme, the rhythm or just for artistic license. Also, language changes over 400 years, so you can't necessarily apply all rules and conventions of today's German to it.
In this specific case, I would read "für" as a kind of mangled "vor", probably mostly to get the rhyme working:

(...) reiß ab, wo Schloss und Riegel vor.

which in more modern German would be something like

(...) reiß das ab, vor dem Schloss und Riegel sind.

referring to "Himmel Tor und Tür" from the previous verse.
And yes, it sounds old fashioned to a modern native speaker, but that's not unexpected for the reasons outlined above. Many "Christmas classics" reflect the language use of the time they were created, plus the peculiarities of poetic language in general.

The meaning vor of für is covered in DWDS, section II/9 and is marked as dated there.

Thank you, that answers my question. I indeed understand we are talking about a text that is both archaic and poetic (tagged as such) and am not confused about why it might be different to modern German, just how best to understand it in context.
